# Edit & continue not working in VS2015 Update 3 (x64)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, edit-and-continue

After a bit of nightmare getting Vs2015 update 3 installed, as per this [related question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6fb7ee96-83df-4fee-8fad-d773b26336a2/visual-studio-2015-professional-update-3-hangs-when-installing), I rebuilt my MFC C++ project to see how the update performed only to find Edit and Continue is no longer working!  Specifically, making any change to any file and using **Debug / Apply Code changes** i get the following;

> *myfile.CPP ......\common\myfile.CPP(1): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you
>   forget to add '#include "\cpp\common\stdafx.h"' to your source?
>   Project : error (null) : Build errors occurred.*

The first include in the source file is

```
#include "\cpp\common\StdAfx.h"
```

This worked most of the time under update 2, but edit and continue was failing and reporting that it had succeeded reasonably regularly.  Only reason I installed this update as it was supposed to fix this issue but now it is broken entirely and I'm looking at a full uninstall, and re-install of VS2015 update 2 over the weekend.

Anyone else hitting this problem and have a solution?  Could possibly be a dodgy installation as even on the full ISO install, the installer failed with missing files and I had to skip two sections.  Given this is a release and not a release candidate, the QA seems abysmal, I fail to see why a release version would include any beta functionality.  VS2015 detail below;

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25421.03 Update
>   3 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015   00325-60000-80195-AA437 Microsoft
>   LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00325-60000-80195-AA437 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00325-60000-80195-AA437 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00325-60000-80195-AA437 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.0.20622.1
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0 ASP.NET and Web
>   Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.8 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> InstallShield Limited Edition    InstallShield. For more information
>   visit the Flexera Software website at
>   http://www.FlexeraSoftware.com. Copyright © 2015 Flexera Software
>   LLC. All Rights Reserved.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript   1.8.34.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Assist    For more information about Visual Assist, see the
>   Whole Tomato Software website at http://www.WholeTomato.com. Copyright
>   (c) 1997-2016 Whole Tomato Software, Inc.
>
> Visual Commander   2.3 For more information about Visual Commander,
>   see the website at https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/.
>   Copyright (c) 2013-2015 Vlasov Studio.
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.25420.01 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.

(Apologies for the ranty nature of this question, but I also put it up as a caveat for those thinking of installing this update)

Answer (score 2):

Following on from the same discussion on [MSDN here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d90df127-35fc-4f22-84ad-1663f7d49e0c/visual-studio-2015-update-3-breaks-edit-continue-x64?forum=vcgeneral#d90df127-35fc-4f22-84ad-1663f7d49e0c) a [breaking change in update 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/01/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015-update-3/) is as follows

> Allow Precompiling (Native only): The debug option Debug > Options >
>   General > Allow Precompiling (Native only) is no longer supported with
>   Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and the default debugger. This is a legacy
>   setting for a marginal performance improvement that has no functional
>   impact.

Disabling the above and doing a rebuild all fixes edit and continue.

Comment: The default for this option is off.  It would be useful if you can remember why you turned it on.

Comment: @Hans, the project has been upgraded through several versions of Visual Studio from 2010 onwards, I wasn't even aware that the option existed until yesterday.  I would have hoped if the option no longer added value and broke edit and continue it would either be removed or at least a warning issued that it was deprecated.

Comment: It is not a project setting, Tools > Options configures VS settings.

Comment: Not sure why it would be on then, unless it has been carried as a setting from a previous version.  I do have VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013 on the same PC so possibly a setting carried over from one of them.  Either way, if the update no longer supports the setting, surely it simply shouldn't be there.  It begs the question how many other deprecated and damaging settings are lurking under the hood?